# VS2017 debugging on remote Linux - view strings

Tags: linux, visual-studio, remote-debugging

I'm using Visual Studio 2017 to develop a C++ app on a remote Linux machine. First, I run my code on the remote machine and then attach to the remote process using SSH. I attach to Native (GDB) code and hit my breakpoint. The problem is that I can't view the contents of a string received in the debugger.

```
std::string msg_str(static_cast<char*>(incoming.data()), incoming.size());
```

The string above is retrieved via ZeroMQ message. If I do a QuickWatch on msg_str, none of the values are in a human readable form. 
[image]
What I expect to see is:

```
{"message":"mark","color":"#FFAABB","session_id":"XVg32B","x":34,"y":563}
```

What do I need to do in order to view this in the VS2017 debugger?

**edit**

No I'm not compiling with VS. I'm developing a game using the Urho3D engine. On the Linux box I use cmake to create the makefile and then compile/link using make from a SSH bash shell. In VS I get all kinds of build errors.

I've been searching high and low for more information on how to set this project up, to no avail. My biggest problem is that I'm a C# developer trying to come up to speed with C++. The learning curve is pretty steep...

Comment: I don't know if the type you use is a native one, but in that case, you might consider writing a native visualiser.

Comment: @cce1911 - yes, I know you're building on the Linux box but the implication of your note is that your VS project is not driving the build process. I have some questions for you. Which version of GCC, GDB, Linux, CMake are you using? Why have you chosen not to create a makefile or CMake Linux project in VS? Are you building an executable or library?

Comment: @stanthomas gcc version 4.4.0, gdb & Ubuntu 7.11.1, cmake 3.10.1. I am building an executable that will be called by a python2.7 script.

This is an existing project with all the environment variables and include directories defined on the Linux machine. With what I can find, it seems that VS2017 can't open an existing Linux make project. You have to recreate it from scratch. I tried this, but had problems configuring the include dirs. Probably a lack of experience with C++ on my end.

Comment: I've editing the answer below 'cos it's a pain typing anything useful into comments.

Comment: gcc 4.4.0 is almost 10 years old. gdb supports pretty-printing of standard containers but I don't know whether its support extends that far back, and how well VS supports this gdb feature. Try (1) debugging natively on Linux with gdb and (2) using a newer gcc.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that you've attached to the remote process and VS doesn't know that it's supposed to be looking at a `std::string`. Are you able to run your test by building then executing from within VS? Does VS *know* that the source it can see is what's running in the debugger?

It looks like at least some of the string is visible in QuickWatch as `_M_p`. The result you expect doesn't appear to be a simple string, could this have a bearing?

I just tried inspecting `std::string ss ("12345", 5)` in QuickWatch in VS2017 (15.7.3) and the string is displayed exactly as you would expect. But I did compile and run (`F5`) from VS.

========= 18 June

You can create a `makefile` project in VCLinux very easily. Add a new project to your solution and choose `Visual C++ - Cross Platform - Linux - Makefile Project`. Then copy your sources and makefile into the newly created project directory and add them to the VS project. In the project settings, set the `Remote Build` commands, e.g. `cd $(RemoteProjectDir);make debug` and under `Debugging` set the remote command you want executed.

Depending on how complex your project is, it might be worth creating a very simple, stand-alone test to try out remote building and debugging to verify that you can set a breakpoint and correctly visualise a string.

Answer (score 0):

Not the perfect solution, but I do msg_str.c_str() in the immediate window. Probably wouldn't work well for anything beyond the 7bit ascii subset of utf.